# Can't make attachInterrupt() work

Tags: interrupt, isr

I have an accel+gyro sensor connected to an Arduino Zero. It's configured to output an interrupt signal on pin 2 when tapped. I can do a `digitalRead()` on the pin, and it does go high, so the interrupt from the sensor is triggering as expected.

However, when I try to `attachInterrupt()` to that pin, so I can update a Boolean variable to use later in the code, it doesn't work; the boolean variable never updates.

Am I doing something wrong in the code, or is it a hardware issue? Thank you for your help.

```
byte int2 = 2;
int int2_val;
volatile boolean tapcheck = false;
    
void interrupt_setup() {
  // set up the sensor to fire interrupts
  // ...

  pinMode(int2, INPUT);
  
  // attach an interrupt on pin 2
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(int2), tapdummyf, RISING);
}
    
// double tap ISR function
void tapdummyf () {
  tapcheck = !tapcheck;
}
    
void interrupt_test() {
  int2_val = digitalRead(int2);
  if (int2_val == 1) {
    SerialUSB.println ("interrupt triggered ");
    int2_val = 0;
  }
}

void loop(void) {
// in loop
  interrupt_test();
    if (tapcheck){
          SerialUSB.println("dt1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pin 2 has been known to be iffy in the past (see https://forum.arduino.cc/t/zero-attachinterrupt/331384). Try using a different pin

Comment: @Majenko that was indeed the issue, wow go figure. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Pin 2 on Arduino M0 is the only pin on headers which doesn't support external interrupt because it is mapped to SAMD21G pin PA08 which is the only pin of SAMD which can't be multiplexed as external interrupt (because it is the only pin which supports NMI).

On Arduino Zero SAMD pin PA08 is mapped to headers pin 4, which is a better choice for a board in Uno format since on Uno only pins 2 and 3 support external interrupt. Maybe there was originally an idea that NMI (non-maskable interrupt) is an even better external interrupt.

Function attachInterrupt requires a pin which support external interrupt.

It looks like you have an Arduino M0 board, not Arduino Zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an external pulldown resistor on your input pin, 10K would probably be ideal, tapcheck will only be true on alternate interrupts as you're toggling it.

Comment: Thank you. Issue was pin 2 iffy with interrupts.